# Mongoose error with PUT request but not with POST or GET

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, schema, put

I have a schema that looks like:

```
    const houseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        address: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            trim: true,
        },
        city: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        roofType: {
            type: String,
            //required: true,
        },
        repairType: {
            type: String,
            //required: true,
        },
        numFloors: {
            type: Number,
            //required: true,
        },
        isOwner: {
            type: Boolean,
            //required: true,
        },
        isGated: {
            type: Boolean
        },
        includeFlat: {
            type: Boolean
        },
        
        addedBy: [
            {
                name:{
                    type: String
                },
                time:{ 
                    type: String
                },
            }    
        ],
    });

    const customerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        firstName: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            trim: true,
        },
        lastName: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            trim: true,
        },
        phoneNumber: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
        },
        //array of houseSchema objects
        properties: [
            houseSchema
        ],

    });
```

And my endpoint that is used to update one of the 'properties' is:

```
router.route('/property').post(async (req,res) => {
    const body = req.body;
    Customer.updateOne({_id: req.query.id, properties: {$elemMatch: {_id: req.query.pId}}},
        {
            $set: {
                "properties.$.address": body.address,
                "properties.$.city": body.city,
                "properties.$.roofType": body.roofType,
                "properties.$.repairType": body.repairType,
                "properties.$.numFloors": body.numFloors,
                "properties.$.isOwner": body.isOwner,
                "properties.$.isGated": body.isGated,
                "properties.$.includeFlat": body.includeFlat
            }
        },
        function(err){
            if(err){
                res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err);
            }
            else{
                res.json('Property Updated!');
            }
        }
    )
});
```

The endpoint works mostly fine (it returns the customer and all properties when i only search for and want to modify one of the 'properties') but only when it is a post or a get request and when it is a put request, the error says

> Error: ValidationError: firstName: Path `firstName` is required., lastName: Path `lastName` is required., phoneNumber: Path `phoneNumber` is required.

I dont know if its a big deal or not, but I do not know why this is happening and would like to know. Just to be clear, the goal of this endpoint is to find one of the properties and update its values, not to change anything about a customer or any of their other properties.

Comment: The code that you shared handles only POST requests (http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router.METHOD), so you must have more code since you say that GET requests also work. Can you share that as well?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen the route is the exact same except all you do is change 'POST' to 'GET' or 'PUT' but other than that, nothing changes

Comment: Please complete your question by sharing (a) which middleware you use to fill `req.body` and (b) how the PUT request looks (URL, headers, body).

Comment: Turns out it was a problem with VsCode. After a while my nodemon server would give a message that it is restarting but never that the server was up. I think none of the changes were actually being updated anywhere so my postman was sending and retrieving old information